# How do I force latex to not put padding between paragraphs in multicols environment?

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

Look at this picture:

[image]

For me it's not a problem if section 3 starts in the first column and gets cut off, I'd rather have that than this weird padding on the TOC and between section 1 and 2. How can I avoid this?

Comment: `\raggedcolumns`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with multicols: the problem here is where do you allow LaTeX to break pages (or in this case columns).

The point is LaTeX by default never separates a heading and the first 2 lines of text of it. Furthermore, if you have headings following each other without any text then heading + subheading or even heading + heading (if they are the same level) form a unit.

Now 3. is followed directly by 3.1 and that directly by 3.2 and that directly by 4. With the rules above that means all that + the first 2 lines of 4 form an unbreakable block and that just doesn't fit all together into the first column, hence the split where it is and without \raggedcolumns you get what you show.

Remedy:

- write some text for 3, 3.1 and 3.2 to finish your document and it will get better.
- if in urgent need  without the right text try `\emph{dummy text}` after each heading
- or put `\allowbreak` after them (not really recommented for the final document)

Comment: Okay, thank you very  much. The introduiction and method parts wont be getting longer, so i will '\allowbreak'. But where do i put the \allowbreak?

Comment: @Hans At the point where you want a break to be allowed, e.g., after the \section{...} or \subsection{..} command. But it is really frowned upon to end a column with a heading that has no text following it. I would rather ran the first column short (eg using \newpage) rather than ending the first column with a heading.